# Cannot use import statement outside a module node.js using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have this in index.js
`function sum(a, b) => a + b exports = { sum }`
and in index.spec.js I do

`import { sum } from './index.js'`

then I got error of `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I'm using node v12, what's the problem here? I don't want to use `export defaults` because I have more than 1 function inside index.js

Comment: the problem is import, not export - you can't use import - in nodejs a module can be (there's other ways) denoted by having `.mjs` file extension

Comment: Rewrite your index.js to `export const sum = (a, b) => a + b;`

Answer (score 0):

Try remove `=` and change `exports` to `export` only.

```
function sum(a, b) => a + b

export { sum }
```